# Is there a way to send SMS without opening sms app in react native?

Tags: react-hooks, react-native

I was trying to send sms without opening sms app. I have tried expo sms but no luck. I have also tried few other packages but still nothing...is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [this](https://github.com/briankabiro/react-native-get-sms-android) library is working fine and reached the goals to send a message without going into the default message environment.

```
var phoneNumbers = {
        "addressList": ["+911212121212", "+911212121212"]
      };
    var message = "This is automated test message"
    SmsAndroid.autoSend(
        phoneNumbers,
        message,
        (fail) => {
            console.log('Failed with this error: ' + fail);
        },
        (success) => {
            console.log('SMS sent successfully');
        },
    );
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do this on IOS too?

Comment: I dont think so. IOS is very restrict about everything. so i guess you can do it only on Android without the user concern.

Comment: i got error: Unresolved function or method autoSend(). I have updated my app.json file with permissions since i am using expo.

Comment: try seeing/asking to the devs of the library on this link: https://github.com/briankabiro/react-native-get-sms-android/issues?q=

Comment: Yes it seems it doesnt work with expo because it's not possible to include custom native modules beyond the React Native APIs and components that are available in the Expo client app.

Comment: Expo is kinda bad. I personally hate it.

Comment: I am beginner... i it seemed like a good option... but no anymore...

Comment: yup, not anymore

Comment: I tried everything, but cannot get package running... i have imported everything according to docs but i still get Unresolved function or method autoSend()

Answer (score -1):

You can use this module `npm install react-native-sms --save && react-native link react-native-sms`

Next step add some code:

```
import SendSMS from 'react-native-sms'

 
someFunction() {
    SendSMS.send({
        body: 'The default body of the SMS!',
        recipients: ['0123456789', '9876543210'],
        successTypes: ['sent', 'queued'],
        allowAndroidSendWithoutReadPermission: true
    }, (completed, cancelled, error) => {
 
        console.log('SMS Callback: completed: ' + completed + ' cancelled: ' + cancelled + 'error: ' + error);
 
    });
}
```

Comment: as said on the README.md: `Currently, only user-initiated sending of an SMS is supported`. this doesn't help the question.